# One to many association in Sequelize with Postgresql

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I receive this error whenever I try to create a 1:many association in Sequelize backed by Postgresql.

> Unhandled rejection Error: ProbeProfile is not associated to Profile!

Profile model definition:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Profile = sequelize.define('Profile', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT,
    isDeleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE          
  }, {
    tableName: 'profiles',
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Profile.hasMany(models.ProbeProfile, { as: 'ProbeProfiles' });
      }
    }
  });

  return Profile;
};
```

ProbeProfile model definition:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var ProbeProfile = sequelize.define('ProbeProfile', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
    label: DataTypes.STRING,
    upperThreshold: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    lowerThreshold: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    probeChannel: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    profileId : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    readingDateTime: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        ProbeProfile.belongsTo(models.Profile, { foreignKey: 'profileId' });
      }
    }
  });

  return ProbeProfile;
};
```

And finally, the query I am using:

```
models.Profile.findAll({ where: { id: id },  include: [models.ProbeProfile] }).then(function(rows) {
        cb(rows);
    });
```

Based on what I am seeing here on SO and the Sequelize Express sample, I'm  unsure as to why I am getting this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to having the 'as: ProbeProfiles' in the Profile model definition. To get the query to work, it also has include the 'as'.

```
models.Profile.findAll({ where: { id: id },  include: [{ model: models.ProbeProfile, as: 'ProbeProfiles' }] }).then(function(rows) {
        cb(rows);
    });
```